# Handling changeable key value pairs in meteor collections (schemaless dilemma)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, nosql

How do you solve the problem when some of the key:values pairs in your `.insert` statement are optional (and thus your key:value pairs change all the time) while it’s being executed within a loop (I'm reading hundreds of rows from a table)?

As I only have only 6 mandatory fields in the collection and 6 optional fields I’m not sure how I can elegantly code it so that I don’t have to insert the empty values as well into my collection. With 6 optional fields I have (roughly if my math is correct) 36 different combinations that I have to handle in if clauses, not really practical. That's a dilemma the schemaless MongoDB creates (unless I want to waste space and have many key:value pairs with empty values in my document).

I've tried using a string that is concatenated with the key:value pairs as a parameter. Which isn’t allowed in the `.insert` command (`syntax error`) as meteor expects a `{ key1:value1, key2:value2 }` structure.

I could enter all key:value pairs at once and then fire up to 6 `$unset` to delete those fields again from the document but that isn’t really a practical solution (as it will create a lot of I/O operations when there really should only be 1 I/O operation).

Any suggestions? How do you solve the problem with changeable key value pairs in Meteor? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you show us some code? The prose is great but I would understand better if I could show what your code actually is (even if it's pseudo-code) and why it doesn't work.

Comment: Right now I would think about using a `Match.Pattern` to validate your query object but I have no idea how your actual code looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insertedObject = {}
insertedObject[“price”] = itemPrice;
insertedObject[“name”] = itemName;
if (!! itemNote ) { 
  insertedObject["note"] = itemNote ; 
}
Products.insert(insertedObject);
```

same with selectors/projections in publications where you have optional arguments etc.

Comment: Same is true for an upsert command, you would just use Products.upsert(selectorObject, modifiedObject);

Answer (score 1):

Your code should create the object as object litteral.

```
var obj1 = {foo:"1", bar:"2"}
var obj2 = {foo:"3"} // no bar
```

Then you get Mongo to insert the objects

```
collection.insert(obj1);
collection.insert(obj2);
```